# Get text of LVITEM with LVM_GETITEM and SendMessage in C

Tags: c, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to read text off the listview of another process. So far I have been able to get the count of rows and columns. Now I want to go through each cell and read it. I did a little bit of research, and I found that I needed to use SendMessage to get the LVITEM of each cell. I think LVITEM.iItem has to be the row #, and LVITEM.iSubItem, has to be the column #. Also how would I go about getting the text into my char*. I saw some examples using CString::GetBuffer. But I'm in c so I don't have that, is there an equivalent or some other way to do that?

```
char* itemText;

LVITEM itemInfo = {0};
itemInfo.iItem = r; // r is an int. this should be row # right?
itemInfo.iSubItem = c; // c is an int, this should be the column # right?
itemInfo.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
itemInfo.cchTextMax = 256;
itemInfo.pszText = itemText;
SendMessage(procList, 0x1005, 0, (LPARAM)&itemInfo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the memory block that contains the text is owned by the other process, you will need to pull a few tricks to marshal the text from the process into your process.

Here is a blog post I did back in 2004 demonstrating how this can be done. Beware, you will need to have Admin rights to do this.

http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/08/archive-hacking-my-way-across-process.html

Comment: Alright, that doesn't look too hard. Thanks! How would I choose which cell to read though, is it like I showed in my example or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Lienau, yes you use the iSubItem member to indicate which sub-item (column) you are interested in. I would suggest that you get the code working in your own process first with a local ListView and then add the code to handle the marshaling, that way you know each step of the way what is working and when it breaks.